# What is the AutomationId of my universal windows app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, coded-ui-tests

So, I am developing a Windows 10 app, or Universal app, and want to run some UI tests in addition to my unit tests.

I have created a project of type "Coded UI Test (Windows)". Then I have my test method, where I want to launch my app before I start to assert that buttons exists, etc.

I know I am supposed to use `XamlWindow.Launch` but what should I pass to it? How do I find my app id?

Comment: You're supposed to use point-and-click from the app tile, step 3 in the manual.  Another way is to double-click the project's Package.appxmanifest, Packaging tab, it is the Package Family Name with "!App" appended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can read this post https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn747198.aspx and find what you want at section "Create a coded UI test for windows phone app" in step 3.